# Trying to update child component 1 with data from child component 2 without rerender child 2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, render

I'm generating a heavy JSX array from a loop. 
It creates a lot of table.
I would like to update a Badge with the data on a row selected. But it rerender all my tables. It's pretty long for updating a single badge.
I tried to use `useMemo()` to prevent the creation of the table if my data doesn't change, but the callback fonction from the parent does not update state.

A code example what i'm trying to do =>

```
function App() {
    const [tableData, setTableData] = useState(null)
    const [badgeData, setBadgeData] = useState(null)
    const jsx = useMemo(() => createTable(tableData), [tableData])

    function updateBadge(selectedRows) {
        setBadgeData(addNewRow(selectedRows))
    }


    function createTable(data) {
        let jsx = []
        data.forEach((item) => {
            jsx.push(<TableComponent data={data.var} onRowSelect={updateBadge}/>)
        })
        return jsx;
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <HandleDataGeneration setData={setTableData}/>
            <MyBadgeComponent data={badgeData}/>
            {jsx}
        </div>
    );
}
```

In this case, only the first call to updateBadge function rerender the parent, but not the nexts calls (i guess it's because i don't send the new props and the function is copied and not linked)

Maybe my architecture is bad, or maybe there is some solution for update this badgeComponent without rerender all my Tables. Thanks you for your help

EDIT:

TableComponent

```
const TableCompoennt = React.memo((props) => { // after edit but it was a classic fn
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(props.data ? `panel${props.i}` : false);
    let disabled = false;

    const handleChange = (panel) => (event, isExpanded) => {
        setExpanded(isExpanded ? panel : false);
    };
    if (isNaN(props.data.var)) {
        props.data.var = x
    }
    if (!props.data)
        disabled = true;
    return (
        <ExpansionPanel TransitionProps={{ unmountOnExit: false }} expanded={expanded === `panel${props.i}`} onChange={handleChange(`panel${props.i}`)} disabled={disabled}>
            <ExpansionPanelSummary
                expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon/>}
                aria-controls="panel1bh-content"
                id="panel1bh-header"
            >
                <Tooltip title={props.data.var}>
                <Typography className={classes.heading}>{props.data.var}-{props.data.var}</Typography>
                </Tooltip>
                {!disabled ?
                    <Typography
                        className={classes.secondaryHeading}>{expanded ? "click to hide data" : "click to display data"}</Typography> :
                    <Typography
                        className={classes.secondaryHeading}>no data</Typography>
                }
            </ExpansionPanelSummary>
            <ExpansionPanelDetails>
                <MyTable data={props.data} var={props.var}
                         key={props.i} id={props.i}  style={{width: "100%"}} updateBadge={props.updateBadge}/>
            </ExpansionPanelDetails>
        </ExpansionPanel>
    )
})
```

MyTable

```
export default React.memo((props) => { // same here
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const [rowData, setRowData] = useState(null);
    const [rows, setRows] = useState(props.myRates);

    calcTotal(rows);
    useEffect(() => {
        setRows(props.myRates)
    }, [props]);

    return (
        <div style={{width: "100%"}}>
            {(rows && rows.length) &&
                <div style={{width: "100%"}}>
                    <Modal open={open} rowData={rowData} setRowData={setRowData}
                                setOpen={(value) => setOpen(value)}/>
                    <Paper style={{height: 400, width: '100%'}}>
                    <SimpleTable
                        columns={columns}
                        rows={rows}
                        handleRowClick={(row) =>{
                                setOpen(true);
                                setRowData(row);
                        }}
                        handleSelect={(row) => {
                            if (!row.selected)
                                row.selected = false;
                            row.selected = !row.selected;
                            props.updateBadge(row)
                    }}
                    />
                    </Paper>
                </div>}
        </div>
    );
})
```

SimpleTable

```
const SimpleTable = React.memo((props) =>  {
    const classes = useStyles();
    let dataLabel = generateLabel(props.columns);

    function getRowData(row) {
        props.handleRowClick(row);
    }

    return (
        <TableContainer component={Paper}>
            <Table className={classes.table} aria-label="simple table">
                <TableHead>
                    <TableRow>
                        {dataLabel}
                    </TableRow>
                </TableHead>
                <TableBody>
                    {props.rows.map((row) => (
                        <TableRow key={row.unique_code} selected={row.selected} hover onClick={() => {getRowData(row)}}>
                            {generateRow(props.columns, row)}
                            <TableCell onClick={(event) => {
                                event.stopPropagation();
                            }
                            }>
                                <Checkbox onClick={(event) => {
                                    event.stopPropagation();
                                    props.handleSelect(row);
                                }}
                                />
                            </TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                    ))}

                </TableBody>
            </Table>
        </TableContainer>
    );
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using useMemo inside the App Component, you must make use of React.memo for the `TableComponent` assuming its a functional component or `extend it with React.PureComponent` if its a class component

However in such a case, you must make sure that you are not recreating the `updateBadge` Function on each re-render. To make sure of that, use `useCallback` hook

Also don't forget to add a unique key to TableComponent's instances which are rendered from the loop

```
function App() {

    const [tableData, setTableData] = useState(null)
    const [badgeData, setBadgeData] = useState(null)

    const updateBadge = useCallback((selectedRows) {
        setBadgeData(addNewRow(selectedRows))
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <HandleDataGeneration setData={setTableData}/>
            <MyBadgeComponent data={badgeData}/>
            {data.map((item) => {
                return <TableComponent key={item.id} props={item} onRowSelect={updateBadge}/>)
             })}
        </div>
    );

}
```

---

and in TableComponent

```
const TableComponent = React.memo((props) => {
 // Rest of the TableComponent code
})
```

EDIT:

Adding a working demo based on your comment codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-fast-0cq32

Few changes

- made of use of useCallback method and also converted state updater to use callback approach
- Removed the logic for JSON.parse and JSON.stringify and instead stored the entire data in array. The reason for this is that everytime you use JSON.parse it returns you a new object reference and hence memo functionality fails in child since it just does a reference check. This will happen each time your component re-renders i.e on update of badge state.
- if you still need to use JSON.parse and JSON.stringify, add a custom comparator that compares the data values deeply

Comment: Thanks you for your anwser
I think i didn't give enought element about my case because it didn't work yet, my bad.
The TableComponent is wrap in a ExpansionPanel {unmountOnExit false} MaterialUI component who call the Table Component
I send in my "TableComponent" a let i for generate my key (ikr it's a bad practice)

If i useCallBack with empty array on updateBadge, setBadgeData is call once in the parent
i tried to React.memo my wrap of Table, and my Table component: same thing
My table component has a MaterialUi checkbox.
There is some things i didn't understand.

Comment: can you add the TableComponent too in your post. I will update my answer to provide more information

Comment: I don't see a data prop being passed to the table component. I think you need to change that. Also when you click on a table row updateBadge should be called and it should not re-render your TableComponent instances but just re-render the MyBadgeComponent with the updated value

Comment: sorry for the props i just tried to obfuscate some variable for professionals reasons...

I didn't understand the "Also" part: updateBadge (from App) is called when i click on the Checkbox and i would like to rerender MyBadgeComponent without rerender TableComponent.
The code above=> when i click on the Checkbox, the badge value is update but my tables are rerender

Comment: you would need to make sure that when updatedBadge is called there isn't any other prop to Table that is being updated or else using `memo` won't be affective

Comment: The only props that change is the updateBadge fn. If i useCall back with [void] the updateBadge, nothing rerender exepected the first time, and my 40 tables too. App doesn't rerender too, like the fn is call setBadgeData once. I'm really stuck with this probleme, maybe there is another way of doing ?

Comment: The sandBox : https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-feynman-y18xs?file=/src/App.js
It works like my real code

Comment: Added working demo in the answer based on your codesandbox